# Scroll to child window in wx.ScrolledWindow

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a `wx.ScrolledWindow` with some child windows in it.

I would like a function to scroll to a child window.

For example: `scrollToChild(childWindow)`. This function would scroll to the child window.

This function seems very useful but I can't find a function like this in the API. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrolledPanel`, which is a subclass of `ScrolledWindow`, has a [ScrollChildIntoView() method](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel-class.html#ScrollChildIntoView). This seems to meet your needs.